Apple Wallet Not Detecting My Pass (.pkpass) - How to Identify the Issue?
I'm trying to add a pass to Apple Wallet, but it isn't being detected when I attempt to add it. I've created the .pkpass file, and it contains the following files:

en.lproj/
icon.png
icon@2x.png
manifest.json
pass.json
signature

{
  "formatVersion": 1,
  "passTypeIdentifier": "pass.com.yourdomain.com",
  "serialNumber": "123456",
  "teamIdentifier": "5ZXXXXXX",
  "description": "This is an Event Pass",
  "eventTicket": {
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "event",
        "label": "EVENT",
        "value": "Concert"
      }
    ],
    "secondaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "location",
        "label": "LOCATION",
        "value": "Example Venue"
      },
      {
        "key": "date",
        "label": "DATE",
        "value": "2024-08-15"
      }
    ],
    "auxiliaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "time",
        "label": "TIME",
        "value": "7:00 PM"
      }
    ],
    "backFields": [
      {
        "key": "terms",
        "label": "TERMS & CONDITIONS",
        "value": "Non-refundable. Please arrive 30 minutes early."
      }
    ],
    "barcode": {
      "message": "1234567890",
      "format": "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
      "messageEncoding": "iso-8859-1"
    }
  },
  "organizationName": "ORGANIZATION NAME",
  "logoText": "Concert 2024",
  "foregroundColor": "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
  "backgroundColor": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
  "eventTicketStrip": {
    "primaryFields": [
      {
        "key": "event",
        "label": "Event",
        "value": "Concert"
      }
    ]
  },
  "relevantDate": "2024-08-15T19:00:00Z"
}

My Questions:

What could be preventing Apple Wallet from detecting this pass?
How can I verify if the signature is correctly applied?
Are there any recommended online tools or methods to debug this pass and identify what might be wrong?
I've tried using a few online validators, but the issue persists. Any guidance on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

What I've Done So Far:

Validated the Manifest: The SHA-1 hashes in the manifest.json match the actual files in the package.
Checked the pass.json: It seems to be correctly formatted, and all fields are populated.
Verified Pass Structure: The .pkpass file structure appears to be correct.
Validate with PKpass Validator: It's seems like all points are valid.


If you have an apple computer, you can use the console app and watch the logs. That should help you identify the issue.

Alternatively, you can use something like passkit.com or passninja.com and then compare your pkpass file.

Hello grundyoso,
Yes check in apple computer console app. I got  this error:
"Invalid data error reading pass pass.com.everyticket.official/ABC. Manifest signature did not verify successfully"
do you have idea about this error?

Can you share your manifest.json and pass.json?

I checked the logs but they were so many, and none of them was related to the apple wallet, even when I clicked over the attached pkpass in a mail with the icon of the wallet. How do you filter them?

You can add "Passkit" to the search field to filter for just pass related messages. I added a screen capture to my response to give you an idea of what it looks like.
